# TDrawGrid OnSetEditText fires twice + Inplace Editors + TCustomGrid

Tags: delphi

I have (in D2010) a TDrawGrid on my form. Im handling my OnDrawCell, OnSetEditText, OnSetEditText etc alls gfine there.

If however in the specific situation that you go in a cell that has some text, highlight the text in its entirity, then type some character to replace. Now the OnSetEditText event fires twice in a row from one keypress, firstly with a blank string, then again with a string containing the character you type. Is this correct or a bug? I would have expected to just get the event fired once with the string containing my single character typed.

I am using OnSetEdit text to set other class properties which does stuff like validation, so when the above situation causes my other code to consider momentarily my class properties to be invalid, before imediately being set back to valid again on the 2nd fire, its still having undesriable consequences though and i want to stop that 1st event firing, or get the bets workaround I can.

Now whilst on the subject of grids, may I appeal to you folks for an helpful tips in the folling things. I am fairly new to deplhi from c# (I'm going the other way!) but Im finding the docs to be pretty thin on the ground, and am getting surprisingly limited results googling for things, so your help is really appreciated.

1) Custom Inplace Editors for TDrawGrid - any tips or good links appreciated!
2) For custome inplace editors, am i better off with TDrawGrid or descending my own control from TCustomGrid and going from there?
3) TCustomGrid. I am getting nowhere here... If I create a new component and descend from TCustomGrid I just get an 'abstract error' when i place it my form. Therefore further experimentation is very much canclled - an advice on just even getting started with TCustomGrid appreciated!

My plan is first to get combo boxes (in virtual mode) working as cell editors. Thats a standard VCL control. Afterwards I plan to create my own control based around a virtual combobox but with a search thing at the top to filter the list down (a bit like in the Delphi IDE Tool pallette), and use this component as inlace editor if possible. Im a fair way off that right now! Thanks all

Edit: Remy - Here are my two call stacks from beak point in OnSetEditText. Left is first fire with the empty string, right is 2nd fire with correct string value. The 5 truncated lines in the middle are all references to comctl32.dll in both. Ty.

[Click here for call stack](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?efd45da20b.png)

Comment: Hoo boy.  Grid events.  Grids are very complex beasts, and IME events on them tend to fire multiple times whether you want them to or not.  Your best bet is to design the event handler so that it will still work if it goes off more than once, if possible.

Comment: I see. Only thing I can do the handler is check for empty string. For simple property setting it no prob, as it immediately get set again with the correct value. But I set props in a class that handles validation as grid edits occur, now I have to change the way my app works or get another grid going. Its all down to selecting text in cell then typing. If you select text, hit bkspace, then type it behaves correctly. Hope I can get to bottom of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `OnSetEditText` event is fired whenever the inplace editor's contents are updated for any reason, when a drop-down editor is closed after selecting a different value, a drop-down editor is double-clicked on, or a drop-down editor's `RestoreContents()` method is called.  So you very likely are getting multiple actions updating the editor one after the other.  I suggest you put a breakpoint inside the `TCustomDrawGrid.SetEditText()` method and see what the call stack looks like each time the event is being fired.

Regarding #2, it does not matter what you derive from.  Any TCustomGrid descendant can have a custom inplace editor.  Simply override the virtual `CreateEditor()` method.

Regarding #3, if you are getting an abstrct error when deriving from TCustomGrid directly, then you did not `override` its abstract methods correctly.

A grid already natively supports a drop-down inplace editor that mimics a combobox.  Look at the `TInplaceEditList` class.  You can use the `OnGetPickListItems` event to fill in the editor with values.  Also, have a look at how `TValueListEditor` implements its custom editors.

Comment: Thanks very much Remy, that gives me some interesting leads to go on.

About the original question - the TDrawGrid double fire of OnSetEditText. I took screenshots of my stacks on both events, aside from the value of the string passed in, its 100% identical.  I understand what your saying about other editors etc interfering, but there is none. I reduced it all down to a blank TDrawGrid, i hand the DrawCell and Get/SetEdittext in the simplest way possible, and absolutely nothing more. No drop down editors or anything else is there, its a stripped down as it can be. I just have goEditing true.

Comment: Ahah. I only just realised you can actually see all the source code in of the units! Like grids.pas! Doh. My life just got a WHOLE lot easier :) Still getting the double event fire - it just seems that if the select text of a cell and start typing then the default behaviour of TDrawGrid is to fire off 2 events, the first having an empty string. That dont seem right to me.

Comment: Can you provide the actual call stack screenshots?

Comment: Yes Sir, theres now a link in my orig question. Ty.

Comment: The call stack shows that the inplace editor is reacting to EN_CHANGE notifications being issues by the OS, so the edit field really is operating on two separate changes - clearing the selected Text, followed by the insertion of the typed character.  There is not much you can do about that since it is the OS issuing separate notifications.  I would suggest moving your validation logic out of the OnSetEditText event directly.  Have it call PostMessage() to queue a custom window message, and then do the validation inside that message handler using whatever the current Text is...

Comment: ... that message handler can also remove duplicate posted messages from the message queue, so you are only validating once per group of changes, and the next change after the validation will queue another delayed validation.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed for you expert advice. I shall implement the solution you suggest. ty

Comment: I recently encountered the very same problem in C++ Builder. SetEditText gets called both from the underlying "HideEdit" and "UpdateEdit" both. I tried to implement the PostMessage() approach discussed here, subclassing of the windowproc. It didn't improve anything nor did I  manage to filter out the extra events. From where should PostMessage() be called and how will it improve the situation? (I managed to solve the problem in another way: by setting a flag to true in KeyDown and the same flag to false in MouseDown, then check this flag from SetEditText. Hardly an universal solution though.)

Comment: Call `PostMessage()` in the `OnSetEditText` event handler to post a custom message.  In your message handler, retreive the current `Text` and process it as needed, then call `PeekMessage()` with the `PM_REMOVE` flag in a loop until all duplicates of your custom message are purged.

Answer (score -1):

**On "abstract error"s**:

In **Delphi** the cause of an "abstract error" is the fact you try to instantiate a class with a non-overridden `virtual abstract` method. If you see such errors, you should look at the definitions of the parent object (`TCustomGrid` in this case), to see which of its methods are `virtual abstract`, then you should `override` those function in your descendant class.

*Note, that Delphi (poorly) only requires you to override functions that gets called*, therefore lots of coders out there don't even know the cause of the mentioned behavior.

Comment: No, an abstract error is raised when you **call** an abstract method.

Comment: And this is why I wrote: "Note, that Delphi (poorly) only requires you to override functions that gets called, therefore lots of coders out there don't even know the cause of the mentioned behavior."

Comment: Yes, that part is reasonable. However, the first sentence is factually incorrect.

Comment: The incorrect sentence would be "Delphi throws an "abstract error" on the instantiation of a class with a non-overridden virtual abstract method.". In the present form it only says, the cause of the error is the creation of a class with a non-overridden virtual method, which I don't see in which part is wrong, but I will fix it if it makes you happy.

Comment: Read my first comment again. You say that the error is raised when upon **instantiation** of class that contains abstract methods. But in fact it is raised upon **call** of abstract method.

Comment: No. I wrote _In Delphi an "abstract error" appears when you try to instantiate a class with a non-overridden virtual abstract method._ When as "In case of." not when as "At the **exact time**."/"when **upon**" which is clearly understandable from the rest of the answer. Telling the opposite is nothing but hackling of you.

Comment: By that reasoning, you could also have said, *In Delphi an "abstract error" appears when you run a program.* Programming is all about precision. Humility helps too.

Comment: No. By that reasoning I could also have said, In Delphi an "abstract error" appears when you run a program which has a class with a non-overridden virtual abstract method. _(Just to be precise.)_ - Which was my goal with that sentence.

Comment: You seem to be incapable of accepting criticism. When you get something wrong, you just fix it and move on. This keeps happening with you. Only yesterday you refused to admit multiple clear and significant errors in an answer. How can you expect to learn if you refuse to see your own mistakes. We all make mistakes. Those of us that are incapable of accepting that are doomed to make more and more. Instead of regarding this as "heckling" or "verbal abuse", you could learn something.

Comment: As I clearly explained in this case there was no error in my answer. **You were also unable to point any errors out.** It was only a lack of _precision_ in **your evaluation of my answer**, and a lack of _humility_ to admit, that you are not right.

Comment: So be it. Obviously you are beyond help.